# Не могу заполнить массив при помощи getchar

Tags: c, массивы, char

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a[1000];
    int c, n;
    int i = 0;
    scanf_s("%d", &n); // задаю размер массива (например 3)
    a[0] = getchar(); // 1 элемент массива  = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = getchar() - '0'; // запись в массив;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]); (выдает просто 0) 
}
```

массив не хочет заполняться при помощи getchar(), но вроде как такое возможно, пожалуйста посмотрите код, и скажите , в чем проблема. Хочу заполнить массив при помощи getchar() задать размер массива, в последующем записать цифры в массив.
задаю размер (пример - 3) и он сразу выводит 0; Но хочу чтобы можно было заполнить массив цифрами. (пример 3, записать 1 2 3 , выдать 1 2 3)

Comment: Что значит *`"массив не хочет заполняться"`*? / Опишите, что вы вводите, что видите и что надеялись увидеть

Comment: ввожу 2 - размер массива, заполняю например 1 2, хочу увидеть на выводе 1 2

Comment: в реалиях, ввожу 3 вижу (0)фигу

Comment: `getchar()` читает в том числе и пробелы. Попробуйте ввести `3 123` и вы должны увидеть на печати `123`

Comment: a[0] = getchar(); - эта строчка задает 1 элемент массиву 0 , то есть, при вводе последующих чисел, он меняет его. заполняю я его подряд.

Comment: Вот тут `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` вы опять его заполняете. Первый getchar пропустит единичный пробел. Да вы, просто попробуйте. Набейте ровно 6 символов -- 3 <пробел> 123 <Enter>

Comment: как тогда исправить? при вводе 3 1 2 3 вывод 49(ascii)10(50)

Comment: Что именно исправить? Вы напишите суть своей задачи, что вы хотите сделать в своем коде. В каком формате собираетесь вводить данные. Сейчас вы вводите размер и после пробела цифры (без пробелов между ними). Массив заполняется числами соответствующими этим цифрам. Я не понимаю,  как у вас получилось `49(ascii)10(50` (может уже в коде программы что-то изменили?)

Comment: спасибо что позадавали вопросы, все решилось само собой